# How do scientists determine how big a certain star is?

Tags: the-sun, stars

I was just wondering, many people say that there are stars that are waay bigger than our sun and in some videos they even try to say the exact diameter of the Sun, but I was wondering: How can scientists know for sure?

Comment: it's a good question. While there is a lot of overlap between [Astronomy SE](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/) and this site, questions about how properties of other stars are measured and/or calculated really belong in the other site. I think this will be closed soon and there's a chance it will be migrated. That's not a bad thing, it's sometimes hard to judge ahead of time exactly where to best ask a question. Also, I'd say that scientists never say they know anything "for sure". That's not how science works. So I've made a slight adjustment to your question.

Answer (score 2):

We can tell how hot a star is by its colour, and (at least in some cases) how far away it is by how it appears to move in the sky as the Earth goes around the sun. We know how bright it is by direct measurement and we know how much light an object at that temperature emits per unit area. From these four numbers we can solve for the size of the star.

More recently, for the nearest and largest stars, we can actually measure the diameter of stars disk directly, using powerful telescopes and special techniques.

Comment: Regarding that first part, so basically they estimate, based on the brighness, how big it must be, according to our understanding of how bright something must be based on how big it is? But what if they are brighter, but for some reason we don't know, smaller than our understanding of temperture per area? In other words, is method #1 basically just an approximation based on certain assumptions? Also, regarding method #2, what are those "special tecnicques" exactly? What I'm trying to get at is, what if all of the distant stars we know of are actually smaller than believed?

Comment: Also looking at this a second time, it also seems that the way for measuringits heatin the first place is just based on the color, but the color-to-heat equation (whaever it is) seems to be just a theory, right? I mean what if theres some other reason that some stars are blue and some are red, is there a way to know for sure that its based on heat, or is that also just a theory?

Comment: “Just a theory” isn’t really a useful phrase here. Black-body radiation is _really_ well studied both experimentally and theoretically.

Comment: All I'm asking if its proven absolutely without a doubt, or if they're just using speculation, whether estimated guessing or otherwise?

Comment: Even if the color did show the heat, but how do they know for sure that it has to be a certain size to give a certain amount of heat?

Comment: @bluejayke Scientists have studied the radiation of heat and light by hot objects for a couple of centuries here on Earth. They have built up a very detailed understanding based on and confirmed by many experiments. The light of stars fits that understanding more or less perfectly, provided each star is a certain size and temperature, and doesn't fit it otherwise.  So they are as sure as they can be.

Comment: @bluejayke There are a number of techniques for directly measuring the sizes of the disks of stars. They are a bit complicated to explain in a stack exchange comment, but they mostly come down to interferometry which you can google. By combining the light or radio waves from multiple telescopes, you can simulate the images that would be produced by a single much larger telescope, powerful enough to actually *see* the disk of the stars.

Comment: @bluejayke Finally, nothing in science is ever "proven absolutely without a doubt". That's not how science works. All that we can say is that a wide range of different experiments and observations made by different people with different instruments, etc. all support a particular interpretation and are not consistent with specific alternative interpretations. That is, how, for instance, I know that the Sum rises in the mornings (at this latitude).

Comment: I also just realied that this whole thing is dependant on the distance, which is itself measured just by its rotation patterns, ASSUMING that the earth goes around the sun, but if the sun and everything else in fact goes around the earth, then those distance (and consequently, size) calculations should change too, right? Isn't the distance the deciding factor, and that itself is only measured based on assumptions from orbit patterns?

Answer (score 0):

I'll address

> ...and in some videos they even try to say the exact diameter of the Sun.

Unlike rocky bodies like the inner planets, The Sun is fuzzy and it has no clear edge. Instead, a number for the diameter of the Sun must come together with a definition of how the edge is determined, and there are more than one way to do this.

According to Wikipedia's [Sun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun) the Sun's equatorial radius can be [695,700 km](https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.07674) or [696,342 km](https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.4898).

The first uses a definition of the Sun's "photospheric radius" where the opacity $\tau$ reaches 2/3. The second uses timing measurements from the 2003 and 2006 transits of Mercury.

Comment: SO why is the sun unique from all other stars in that we can measure it? Is it just because its closer or fuzzy?

Comment: @bluejayke oh, only because it is so darn close! We've been abel to study it using all kinds of techniques on the ground for centuries and in space for a half-century all at relatively close range. Otherwise there isn't anything particularly measurable or otherwise special about our star.